# Oracle statement

Tags: oracle

Tables records as below

```
D:\HOME\DOC\FILE\2001\12\TT-12S2Q99-EE-EE1.pdf  
D:\HOME\DOC\FILE\2002\02\TT-12S2Q94-EE-EE1.xml  
D:\HOME\DOC\FILE\2005\05\TT-12S2Q98-EE-EE1.pdf  
D:\HOME\DOCS\TEMPFILE\TT-12S2Q88-EE-EE1.pdf
```

I want to extract those file names only. The result should be

```
TT-12S2Q99-EE-EE1    
TT-12S2Q94-EE-EE1   
TT-12S2Q98-EE-EE1    
TT-12S2Q88-EE-EE1
```

Anyone can give me a hand ?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`INSTR`](http://psoug.org/reference/substr_instr.html) with the third parameter negative to search backwards in the string from the end (something I didn't know you could do until a few minutes ago).  Combine that with a `SUBSTR` and you should have what you want:

```
SQL> select filename from mytable;

FILENAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\path\to\some\file.txt

SQL> select substr(filename, instr(filename, '\', -1) + 1) from mytable;

SUBSTR(FILENAME,INSTR(FILENAME,'\',-1)+1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the SUBSTR and INSTR functions.

If you're still stuck after that, post your best attempt at what you've done.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's not a spoon-fed answer, no.  But since the OP had seemly not made any attempt to try to answer the question themselves, I provided some pointers to help them along.  I would have left a comment, but I don't think stackoverflow had comments at the time (it's an answer from back in March 2011)

Comment: Yeah you're right. Maybe not such a good idea to show these old answer in the "Low quality posts" queue as the current standards may not have applied then.