# Is there a library function to split file and parent directory in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Given a file path I am trying to separate file name and the parent directory in Oracle PL/SQL. I am wondering if there is already a function available in PL/SQL libraries

Comment: Very similar (if not duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367315

Answer (score 3):

There's no real need, if you're in 10g or later it's just needs a bit of regular expression finessing, which, depending on your OS might look as follows:

```
with filepaths as (
  select '/home/oracle/somedir/blah.sql' as linux
       , 'c:\home\oracle\somedir\blah.sql' as windows
    from dual
         )
select regexp_substr(linux, '[^/]+', 1
                     , regexp_count(linux,'/')) as linux
     , regexp_substr(windows, '[^\]+', 1
                     , regexp_count(windows,'[^\]+')) as windows
  from filepaths
       ;

LINUX    WINDOWS
-------- --------
blah.sql blah.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

The INSTR and SUBSTR string functions can be used to do this, as follows:

```
WITH filepaths AS
  (SELECT '/home/oracle/somedir/blah.sql' AS LINUX,
          'c:\home\oracle\somedir\blah.sql' AS WINDOWS
     FROM DUAL)
SELECT LINUX,
       SUBSTR(LINUX, 1, INSTR(LINUX, '/', -1)) AS LINUX_PATH,
       SUBSTR(LINUX, INSTR(LINUX, '/', -1)+1) AS LINUX_FILE,
       WINDOWS,
       SUBSTR(WINDOWS, 1, INSTR(WINDOWS, '\', -1)) AS WINDOWS_PATH,
       SUBSTR(WINDOWS, INSTR(WINDOWS, '\', -1)+1) AS WINDOWS_FILE
FROM filepaths;

LINUX         /home/oracle/somedir/blah.sql
LINUX_PATH    /home/oracle/somedir/
LINUX_FILE    blah.sql
WINDOWS       c:\home\oracle\somedir\blah.sql
WINDOWS_PATH  c:\home\oracle\somedir\
WINDOWS_FILE  blah.sql
```

Share and enjoy.