# Trim string up to certain character in sql (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, trim, substr

Looking for some help here if anyone can offer some.  I am working with an oracle database and I would like to trim a string up until a certain character '/'.  These fields are paths of a URL and they are all different sizes so I need to make sure it's getting to the very last '/' in the URL and removing everything up until that point.  Additionally, there is a session ID that is associated with some of these URLs that is located at the end of the string and has a semi-colon before it starts, so I would want to remove everything that contains a semi-colon up to the semi_colon and on.  So essentially I want to remove content from the beginning of the URL and from the end of the URL if applicable.  Examples of these URL's (string) are as follows:

```
Current URLS

/ingaccess/jsp/mslogon.jsp
/ingaccess/help/helpie_term_cash_surrender_value.html
/eportal/logout.do;jsessionid=xr8co1kyebrve47xsjwmzw--.p704
/eportal/logout.do;jsessionid=gdh_e_e1m1hna0z9ednklg--.p705
/ingaccess/help/helpie_term_northern_unit_value.html
/ingaccess/help/helpie_scheduled_rebalance.html
/eportal/home.action;jsessionid=9vhfbkhunkvtcm5g1dtgsa--.p704
/ingaccess/help/helpie_catch_up_50.html
/ingaccess/piechartmaker
/ingaccess/help/helpie_term_fund_balance.html

Desired URLS

mslogon.jsp
helpie_term_cash_surrender_value.html
logout.do
logout.do
helpie_term_northern_unit_value.html
helpie_scheduled_rebalance.html
home.action
helpie_catch_up_50.html
piechartmaker
helpie_term_fund_balance.html
```

Anyone know of an easy fix here?  I've tried working with SUBSTR and REPLACE a bit but can't seem to get them to work.

Thanks a bunch in advance,
Ryan

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367315

Comment: @LukeWoodward Thanks so much, I was looking and looking and didn't happen to see that one.  Sure enough it works like a charm.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Sorry to bring this topic up again, but is there a way to remove everything after the ';' if the string contains it?  For instance,  if the string contains ';jsessionid=9vhfbkhunkvtcm5g1dtgsa--.p704' at the end of it, remove that as well.  So in essence removing everything but the middle.

Thanks Again, Ryan

Comment: Something like `select case when value like '%;%' then substr(value, 1, instr(value, ';') - 1) else value end from some_table` should do.  Change `value` and `some_table` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR (surname,';')>0 THEN SUBSTR(surname,1
             ,INSTR(surname,';',1,1)-1) ELSE surname END FROM
(SELECT SUBSTR(column,INSTR(column,'/',-1)+1) AS surname
 FROM tableName)
```

Tested on Apex